# a single script in node to get authToken from some xyz oath2 /token end point and call the following api. I have coded something like this below

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

// getToken.mjs

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
import qs from 'qs';
var data = qs.stringify({
  'client_id': 'xxxx-xxx',
  'client_secret':  'xxxx-xxx',
  'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials' 
});
const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   },
  data : data
};

export let accessToken = axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log((response.data.access_token));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

--------- Calling the API in the second script -----

//get response.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { accessToken } from "./getToken.mjs";
const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  }
};


export let data000 = axios(config).then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});


console.log(data000);
```

---

On executing the > node response.js ...  returns 401, client secret, and id is correct. However, I feel the accessToken is not getting imported and hence the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: 1. In my understanding the request should be POST.
2. Did you get Access Token?
3. If you got Access Token , is that working with `'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` endpoint? by simple curl from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `POST` method to get `accessToken`.

```
const config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   },
  data : data
};
```

Comment: same result with POST too.